# storing a composite pattern (tree) in CoreData with Restkit

Tags: ios, core-data, tree, restkit, composite

I have create an composite object (tree structure) in visual studio and stored in an sql server database with.
here are the screenshots:
now I want to create this model schema in core data and store the received data with RestKi.

[image]
[image]

here what I have designed with Xcode:
[image]

could someone help me to store this data with RestKit which I get in json ?

```
//Initialize managed object store
.
.
.

//Complete Core Data stack initialization
.
.
.

RKEntityMapping *menuMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Menu" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    menuMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"menuComponentID"];
    [menuMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"ID":@"menuComponentID",
                                                     @"Name":@"name",
                                                     @"Description":@"descriptions",
                                                     @"Thumbnail":@"thumbnail",
                                                     @"Image": @"image",

                                                     }];

    RKEntityMapping *menuItemMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MenuItem" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [menuItemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                          @"ID" : @"menuComponentID",
                                                          @"Description" : @"descriptions",
                                                          @"Name" : @"name",
                                                          @"Thumbnail":@"thumbnail",
                                                          @"Image":@"image",
                                                          @"Calorie":@"calorie",
                                                          @"Vegeterian":@"vegeterian",
                                                         }];
    RKRelationshipMapping *menuRelationShip = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"MenuComponents" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:menuMapping];
    [menuMapping addPropertyMapping:menuRelationShip];

    RKResponseDescriptor *menuResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:menuMapping
                                                                                                method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                           pathPattern:@"/api/menu/"
                                                                                               keyPath:nil
                                                                                           statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:menuResponseDescriptor];
```

managed objects: 
menuComponnet.h

```
@class MenuComponent;

@interface MenuComponent : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descriptions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * menuComponentID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MenuComponent *parent;

@end
```

////

menu.h

```
@class MenuComponent;

@interface Menu : MenuComponent

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *children;
@end

@interface Menu (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addChildrenObject:(MenuComponent *)value;
- (void)removeChildrenObject:(MenuComponent *)value;
- (void)addChildren:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeChildren:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

menuItem.h

```
@interface MenuItem : MenuComponent

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * price;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * calorie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * vegeterian;

@end
```

when I browse the created sqlite data base. I see there is only one created table name `menuComponent` which has all attributes of all menu and and menuItem. while nhibernate bas created for me three table as you see in the above picture.
and parent field for all of the records is null!!

**how can I successfully store this data? please explain. I'm new to RestKit.**

**Default JSON I got:**

```
[{"ID":"213028b8-9f59-4d7f-bae9-a2c301815a43","MenuComponents":[{"ID":"d1a861d3-d9e8-41a4-9577-a2c301815a44","MenuComponents":[{"ID":"fa6d172d-ab26-4782-8306-a2c301815a44","Vegetarian":false,"Calorie":0,"Name":"Double Chocolate Cake","Description":"With a melted heart of chocolate","Parent":{"ID":"d1a861d3-d9e8-41a4-9577-a2c301815a44"},"Version":"AAAAAAAAF64="},{"ID":"f9050f6b-8419-4457-9ebd-a2c301815a44","Vegetarian":false,"Calorie":0,"Name":"Tiramisu","Description":"Lady finger cookies are soaked in coffee liqueur and rum","Parent":{"ID":"d1a861d3-d9e8-41a4-9577-a2c301815a44"},"Version":"AAAAAAAAF60="}],"Name":"Dessets Menu","Description":"Desserts for serving after meal","Parent":{"ID":"213028b8-9f59-4d7f-bae9-a2c301815a43"},"Version":"AAAAAAAAF6o="},{"ID":"1f50565a-eeb2-4ab0-ba7b-a2c301815a44","MenuComponents":[{"ID":"0352c5a2-081a-496d-86aa-a2c301815a44","Vegetarian":true,"Calorie":0,"Name":"Grilled Chicken Salad","Description":"Sliced, grilled chicken tops a fresh salad mix, peas","Parent":{"ID":"1f50565a-eeb2-4ab0-ba7b-a2c301815a44"},"Version":"AAAAAAAAF6w="},{"ID":"4fad8aa0-285f-4419-b85e-a2c301815a44","Vegetarian":true,"Calorie":0,"Name":"Carolina Chicken Salad","Description":"Salad mix, fried chicken tenders, peas, cheddar cheese","Parent":{"ID":"1f50565a-eeb2-4ab0-ba7b-a2c301815a44"},"Version":"AAAAAAAAF6s="}],"Name":"Salad & Combinations","Description":"Salad & Combinations","Parent":{"ID":"213028b8-9f59-4d7f-bae9-a2c301815a43"},"Version":"AAAAAAAAF6k="}],"Name":"Lunch Menu","Description":"Lunch Super Menu","Version":"AAAAAAAAF6E="},{"ID":"fa6d172d-ab26-4782-8306-a2c301815a44"},{"ID":"0352c5a2-081a-496d-86aa-a2c301815a44"},{"ID":"d1a861d3-d9e8-41a4-9577-a2c301815a44"},{"ID":"f9050f6b-8419-4457-9ebd-a2c301815a44"},{"ID":"4fad8aa0-285f-4419-b85e-a2c301815a44"},{"ID":"1f50565a-eeb2-4ab0-ba7b-a2c301815a44"}]
```

you can view the json here:

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

**UPDATE:**

here is menuComponent RelationShip

```
RKRelationshipMapping *menuComponentRelationShip = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"MenuComponents" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:menuComponentMapping];
```

[menuComponentMapping addPropertyMapping:menuComponentRelationShip];

but I must map menuItem too because some property are exclusively for menuItem.

```
  RKEntityMapping *menuItemMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MenuItem" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [menuItemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                          @"ID" : @"menuComponentID",
                                                          @"Description" : @"descriptions",
                                                          @"Name" : @"name",
                                                          @"Thumbnail":@"thumbnail",
                                                          @"Image":@"image",
                                                          @"Prcie":@"price",
                                                          @"Calorie":@"calorie",
                                                          @"Vegeterian":@"vegeterian",
                                                         }];
RKResponseDescriptor *menuItemresponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:menuItemMapping
                                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                               pathPattern:@"/api/menu/"
                                                                                                   keyPath:nil
                                                                                               statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:menuItemresponseDescriptor];
```

but after adding this responseDescriptor to mobjetManager only addes one super menu!!
How can I map menuItem and add them to database too?

Comment: Your source data model isn't important. The JSON is however and you **must** show that before we can help.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Do you have any control to change the JSON? Do you have to take the JSON as nested data?

Comment: json updated. I get this json from firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue doesn't seem to be related to RestKit at all, rather it is misunderstandings about Core Data.

1. Your children relationship should be on menu component and the inverse of the parent relationship. This allows Core Data to manage the relationships correctly (and as you expect).
2. You should only have 1 table in the SQLite DB file because you are using entity inheritance (it isn't a problem, just an implementation detail).

So just change the relationship in the model and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have designed the model followed this idea: 1. every menuComponent has a parent. 2. **only menu has children.** every menu has menuComponents (children) but every menuComponent is not necessary to have a menu. (so children relationship doesn't have an inverse).

Comment: While that may seem logical, it just causes you problems. Having a generic relationship doesn't mean you have to use it. Make it generic and use it where appropriate...

Comment: I followed your advice. it works but **1. now there isn't column named children!!!** and **2.rest kit also adds a an empty row too!** here is a shot:http://demo.chevereto.com/dLb   whats your idea? both parent and children are optional because some menu doesn't have parents and all of menuItem doesn't have any children.

Comment: Don't look at the SQLite. Query the context and log what it returns. The menu item mapping should have an `identificationAttributes`. Do you have any other response descriptors?

Comment: I think I should have 2 response descriptor one for menuComponent and one for menuItem. just see the updated code. I think there is a problem with my response descriptors.

Comment: You should only have 1 response descriptor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46515/discussion-between-hashem-aboonajmi-and-wain)